# ServiceBusTrigger not retrying abandonned messages?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs, servicebus, azure-webjobssdk

I have a problem with a webjob destroying messages from service bus topic if an exception occurs.  I want the message to stay on the topic (for the subscription) until it processes successfully.  Even if that means messages are behind it are blocked until the first message succeeds.

We have a web job that processes messages on a Service Bus Topic using a trigger, example below:

```
[Singleton]
    public void ProcessQueueMessage([ServiceBusTrigger("%TopicNameEvent%", "%SubscriptionNameEvent%")] BrokeredMessage message, TextWriter log)
    {
        lock (MsgLock)
        {
            log.WriteLine($"{DateTime.UtcNow} - Event processing started for Message Id {message.MessageId}.");

            var proc = new MessageProcessor();
            proc.ProcessBrokeredMessage(message);

            log.WriteLine($"{DateTime.UtcNow} - Event processing finished for Message Id {message.MessageId}.");
        }
    }
```

In the ProcessBrokeredMessage() call, I will fabricate an exception being thrown like this:

```
public void ProcessBrokeredMessage(BrokeredMessage message)
    {
        try
        {
            throw new Exception("blah blah blah");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    _log.Error(ex);  // Log what caused exception
            throw;  // Rethrow in the hopes that the message will stick and not be abandoned ....
        }
    }
```

What I find happens is that when the exception occurs, the message is abandoned, and then the subsequent message is triggered.  It did not retry the message that threw the exception?  My understanding of the SDK is that it should only complete the message processing on success and that an exception would keep the message alive for the subscription?

This is how we create the Service Bus client configuration:

```
_subClient = SubscriptionClient.CreateFromConnectionString(_servicesBusConnectionString, _feedName, _subscriptionName);
        _subClient.RetryPolicy = RetryPolicy.Default;
        var config = new JobHostConfiguration
        {
            JobActivator = new NinjectActivator(_ninjectKernel),
            NameResolver = new TopicNameResolver()
        };
        var sbConfig = new ServiceBusConfiguration {ConnectionString = _servicesBusConnectionString};
        sbConfig.MessageOptions.MaxConcurrentCalls = 1;  // We only want to process one message at a time, in order
        config.UseServiceBus(sbConfig);

        // block the host process
        _host = new JobHost(config);
        _host.RunAndBlock();
```

I did try some code about setting the Dequeue count (example:  Queues = {MaxDequeueCount = 100 } // try 100 times)   But that doesn't work either.

UPDATE:

DeadLetterMessageCount remains the same before and after processing the message that raises an exception.  Before processing is 14.  After processing remains at 14:

[image]

UPDATE #2:

Okay, so I decided to write the Message IDs to a text file when the exception occurs.  Looks like it *does* try the message again when an exception occurs.  But no guarantees as to when it does ...   Bolded IDs below that are the same, to show when they tried again

1932248
1932324
1932259
1932233
1932308
1932249
1932250
1932240
1932333
1932226
1932231
1932247
1932229
**1932234**
1932334
1932232
1932220
1932259
1932333
1932229
**1932234**
1932220
1932226
1932247
1932248
1932250
1932240
1932233
1932232
1932249
1932324
1932231
1932334
1932259
1932334
1932229
1932333
1932226
1932232
1932247
1932248
1932240
1932249
1932324
**1932234**
1932250
1932424
1932233
1932231
1932333
1932334

UPDATE #3:
Ok, I can confirm it will eventually retry the message 10 times before moving to the Dead Letter Queue.

I just need to figure out now how to make the web job stop processing everything when an exception occurs, until the same message can succeed (most likely wait for a human to fix something, redeploy new code, fix database issue, etc).

Comment: Do the abandoned message end up in the dead letter queue or is it completely gone?

Comment: DeadLetterMessageCount remained the same before and after processing the message that raised the exception.  Have updated question with screenshot

Comment: I am sure there is a better solution to this, but for the sake of trying to make it work: try to do message.Abandon() in your catch block. That should put the message back in the queue.

Comment: Hi Jimmy, I tried that too.  I tried doing a message.Abandon() just before the throw (inside the catch) but it still ignores it and picks up the next message next time around.  :(

Comment: I am not sure about the exact behavior, but it might be that there is a "hold off" time to a message if it is flagged as "poisonous". That could mean that the service bus will continue to deliver other messages while waiting for this time to expire.

Comment: Btw, have you tried using https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer to analyse your issues? It is a bit rough and buggy but I think it is quite helpful when trying to understand what is happening on the servicebus.